# How can I access WAMP from LAN without 'Puting Online'?

Tags: lan, webserver, wamp

I know I can put the server online. But I don't want the server accessible through the internet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Adding "Allow from 192.168.1.12" below "Allow from 127.0.0.1" to the http.conf worked for me. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Allow from {yourIP}" below "Allow from 127.0.0.1" to the http.conf

Comment: Don't you mean httpd.conf? (Nitpicky I know, but for people new to this, they may get confused..). explicitly limiting apache to a specific set of local IP addresses is a great idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Allow access to port 80 only from the LAN, not from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the configuration of apache, but I'd suggest installing a proper firewall on the machine and only accept IP ranges in your LAN on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vanilla installation of WAMP version 2.2 installed on Windows 7 Pro, but, I am using a custom port (as IIS 7 is already using port 80). When I followed Kelbizzle's answer, my httpd.conf file already had 'Allow from all' permissions set for the \wamp\www folder (default). All I had to do is add an exception to the Windows Firewall for the port I was using to fix this problem.